# How do i apply my understanding of O(log N) to this specific function?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

So, my understanding of O(log n) is that time increases linearly while n increases exponentially. I'm trying to apply this understanding to the following function from interviewbit:

```
int a = 0, i = N;
    while (i > 0) {
        a += i;
        i /= 2;
    }
```

I can't seem to arrive at an understanding of why the time complexity is O(log n). Can anyone break this down and explain why?

Comment: In this example, the value a in no way affects the number of loops, so it isn't relevant to the Big-O evaluation of this algorithm. You can remove it and arrive at the same evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example you need to count the loop iterations, as the the number of these iterations determines the total time your algorithm needs.

As `i` is divided by 2 in each iteration, we have `log N` iterations of the loop (easier to understand with log base 2, but this doesn't really matter).

Example: For N=64 you have 7 iterations, the first with i=64, the second with i=32, then 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 and finally the loop stops after dividing `i=1/2` giving 0 (in integer arithmetic). If you double N to 128, you have 8 iterations. If you double N again to 256, you have 9 iterations. Here you see the exponential growth in N while having a linear growth in the number of loop iterations (i.e., time).

Comment: Yes. This example would be easier to understand with `i >= 1`, as this matches the intuition. For non-integer division leading to 4/2/1/0.5/0.25/... the algorithm obviously runs longer (and I can't tell how long exactly without knowing the details of the division in use). In complexity theory you don't really care about implementation details which only influence the constant factor.

Comment: With usual semantics (the type `int` taken as a model for integers and the integral division performing a truncation to the next lowest integer) the number of iterations would be the same for all values of `N` which can be represented by `int` respectively.

Comment: Excellent disambiguation! Also, base 2 is much easier to understand in this case, so why does it not matter? I'm trying to take this explanation and derive an understanding of how i could come to this conclusion for any O(log n) algorithm.

Comment: `log_b(n) = log_a(n)/log_a(b)`, in other words you're just off by a constant factor (which only contains a and b, but not n). I don't understand @Codor's comment, as higher values of N also cause more loop iterations. PS: log_2(64) = 6 != 7, but here you can also trick with some constant factor (e.g. 2).

Comment: The base 'does not matter' in the sense that in the light of [change of base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Product.2C_quotient.2C_power_and_root), the specific base is a constant factor in the running time which 'does not matter' in the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @C-Otto My comment above is a bit ambiguous; of course the number of iterations differ for different values of `N`, nur for a fixed value of `N`, the number of iterations is the same on different achitectures. The comment is a remark on a different comment which has disappeared in between.

Comment: Thanks C-Otto and @Codor! I've learned quite a bit from you guys today.